# Integral that does not seem to converge at a single value

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I have the following integral

> $$\int_0^{\pi}e^{\frac{\cos\left(e^{ix}\right)+\cos\left(e^{-ix}\right)}{2}}\cosh\left(\frac{\cos\left(e^{ix}\right)}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{\cos\left(e^{-ix}\right)}{2}\right)dx$$

Now I tried to substitute $z=e^{ix}$ and $z=e^{-ix}$ to try to form a closed path, and thought that this would be equal to
$$\frac{-i}{2}\int_{\gamma}e^{\frac{\cos\left(z\right)+\cos\left(z^{-1}\right)}{2}}\cosh\left(\frac{\cos\left(z\right)}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{\cos\left(z^{-1}\right)}{2}\right)z^{-1}dz$$
where $\gamma$ is unit circle counter-clockwise

Now I tried to use the residue theorem to find the residue at $0$, but this this did not seem to converge, I got a range of values i.e. $\left(\frac{(1+e)^2}{4e},\frac{(1+e)^2}{4}\right)$

**Edit:**

Alright, so I tried to use some sort of Laurent series, and ended up with the following:

Let $$a_1(k)=\frac{1}{(2k)!},$$ $$a_{n+1}(k)=\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{a_n(m)}{(2k-2m)!}$$

with the property that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_n(k)z^{2k}=\cosh^n(z)$$

Now, with some work, I found out that the integral is equal to

$$\pi\sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k_1=0}^{k_1+k_2}\left(\left(\sum_{n_1=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k_1}a_{n_1}(k_1)}{2^{n_1}(n_1)!}\right)\left(\sum_{n_2=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k_2}a_{2n_2}(k_2)}{2^{2n_2}(2n_2)!}\right)\left(\sum_{n_3=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k_3}a_{n_3}(k_3)}{2^{n_3}(n_3)!}\right)\left(\sum_{n_4=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k_1+k_2-k_3}a_{2n_4}(k_1+k_2-k_3)}{2^{2n_4}(2n_4)!}\right)\right)$$

Now, I haven’t numerically checked if this monstrosity works, also, I’m not sure how to simplify this.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The exponential part in the first integral, with a small bit of work, can be transformed into $$\cosh (\cos (\cos (x)) \cosh (\sin (x)))+\sinh (\cos (\cos (x)) \cosh (\sin (x)))$$
Perhaps it's not that useful.
In any case, the numeric evaluation of the integral gives a real value of $12.4819$, rather away from your range.

Comment: @Turing Yes, I know about the numerical approximation, and the range I am getting for the value of the integral is $\left(\frac{(1+e)^2\pi}{4e}, \frac{(1+e)^2\pi}{4}\right)$, with the value not in the range, it seems that residue theorem is not the way to go